# Will attack rating of my sword decrease when leveling up?

Tags: dark-souls-2

I just got a new weapon (Watcher's Greatsword), upgraded it to +5 and infused it with magic.

Now, I wanted to spend my souls on leveling but when I pull up the leveling screen and change the points of an attribute, the attack rating of my main weapon (said greatsword) drops drastically.

Is this **really** the attack rating the sword will have after my level-up? The weapon would become worthless for me. I can only assume this is a bug. I'm stuck with a lot of souls now because I don't want my weapon to loose so much power.

In the top right corner it displays a drop from 487 to 327.

[image: Screenshot DSII]

I also un-equipped the weapon and used another one instead. For other weapons I don't see any decrease. Why would there be any? But, for this one greatsword it shows this huge drop in attack rating.

Anyone got a clue what is going on here? Can I safely level-up with loosing that much attack rating on my greatsword?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turned out to be a bug in the game.

It is related to the *Crown of the Sunken King* which I was wearing at that moment.

The *Watcher's Greatsword* requires 18 strength. I have 17 strength and reach 18 because of the buff from the Crown of the Sunken King.

As soon as I tried to increase one of my stats, the calculation ignored the fact that I was wearing the crown, leading to a false result with 17 strength which is of course too low to use the *Watcher's Greatsword* properly.